# How do I get the current GPIO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

Heyho, 
im a beginner in general and my first project is based on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hP5wbpJOpQ&t=952s

I wrote some code (see below) and my problem is that I can't figure out how to get the last GPIO. I iterate over a list of GPIOs in an if-structrue to make them blink and when a button is pressed it turns a value on true and the iteration over the GPIOs stops.

TO SOLVE:
I iterate over the GPIO list to make them flash and if the the button is pressed the current flashing GPIO continues flashing, the iteration stops

I guess my code isn't clever at all- I'm grateful for all heelp and suggestions..

```
lP = [35, 33, 31, 29, 23, 21, 19, 15, 13, 11, 40]
lP_rev = [11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23, 29, 31, 33]
button = [37, 38]

inp = False

def Flash(who, long):
    GPIO.output(who, True)
    s(long)
    GPIO.output(who, False)
    s(long)


while True:
    if inp == False:
        t = 0.01
        for x in lP:
            Flash(x, t)
        for x in lP_rev:
            Flash(x, t)

    if any(GPIO.input(x) == 0 for x in button):
        print("pressed")
        inp = True
        s(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the state of an GPIO pin if it is set to output, but you could make a variable that counts +1 every time you execute `Flash` and every time it comes to the end of the list of the pins it sets the variable to 0. If you then press the button, it sets the led of the variable high.

```
lP = [35, 33, 31, 29, 23, 21, 19, 15, 13, 11, 40]
button = 37

inp = False
x = 0

while inp == False:
   x = x + 1
   GPIO.output(lP[x], True)
   time.sleep(0.01)
   GPIO.output(lP[x], False)
   time.sleep(0.01)
   if (GPIO.input(button) == 1):
      GPIO.output(lP[x], True)
      time.sleep(1)
      GPIO.output(lP[x], False)
      x = 0
```

Comment: It depends on the driver.